# how to send api key to pushbullet api

Tags: api

i try to get the list of devices from pushpullet API

i'm using this code

```
string api = "my api key";
        string url = "https://" + api + ":@api.pushbullet.com/v2/devices";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

i get 401 "No valid API key provided."

when i try it on [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

it's work fine and i get the response.[pushbullet api](https://docs.pushbullet.com/)